# TFS 2015 API remove agent from pool with PowerShell

Tags: c#, rest, powershell, tfs-2015, build-agent

I'm working on removing an agent from a pool temporarily, install new software on the buildserver the agent is on, test that it works, and then add the agent to the pool again.

I would like to do that programmatically, either with PowerShell or if that isn't a possibility, then do it with C#.

The problem is that I can't find any documentation that can assist me on doing this, either through the TFS REST API or through the tools that come with Visual Studio.

So I'm specifically asking:

How do I remove a named agent from a build pool and
how do I add a named agent back into the build pool?

I basically want the same functionality of going onto the web administration of TFS and unchecking/checking an agent in the pool.

When I try to enable/disable an agent with the information provided by starain-msft, I get the following error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod :
404 - File or directory not found.
Server Error
```

Later I removed much of the error, as I found out that issue lay in my company's proxy.
Read here: *[Azure DevOps Services REST API Reference](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics#http-method-override)*

But I got it to work with the help of starain-msft.

The final solution looks like this:

```
Function TFSwebRequest {
    param
    (
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $Uri,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $Method,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $ContentType,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $ContentBody,

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [System.Net.WebHeaderCollection] $Headers
    )

    # Creating Webrequest from 'Uri'
    $webRequest = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::CreateHttp($Uri)

    $webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
    $webRequest.Method = $Method
    if ($Headers.Count -ne 0) {
        $webRequest.Headers = $Headers
    }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ContentType)) {
        $webRequest.ContentType = $ContentType
    }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ContentBody)) {
        $Body = [byte[]][char[]]$ContentBody
        $Stream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        $Stream.Write($Body, 0, $Body.Length);
    }

    # Get webresponse to a variable
    try {
        [System.Net.WebResponse]$webResponse = $webRequest.GetResponse()
    }
    catch {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Host "TFSwebRequest Failed = " $ErrorMessage -ForegroundColor Red
    }

    # Stream webresponse to a string
    $webResponseStream = $webResponse.GetResponseStream()
    $streamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $webResponseStream
    $result = $streamReader.ReadToEnd() | ConvertFrom-Json

    return ,$result
}

$agentUri = "http://teamfoundation:8080/tfs/Main/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$($poolID)/agents/$($agentID)?api-version=2.3-preview.1"
$contentBody = @"
{
    "maxParallelism": 1,
    "id": INSERTID,
    "enabled": true #Or false
}
"@

$headers = New-Object System.Net.WebHeaderCollection
$headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH")

TFSwebRequest -Uri $agentUri -Method "POST" -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -ContentBody $contentBody
```

Comment: Does your build agent run as service or run in interactive mode?

Comment: I added powershell code and disable/enable build agent REST API to my answer, you can check it.

Comment: Do you solve that issue with my solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REST API of the agent pool and agent:

Get agent pools (request method: GET):

```
http://[TFS URL]/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=2.3-preview.1
```

Get agents of an agent pool (Request method: GET):

```
http://[TFS URL]/_apis/distributedtask/pools/[pool id]/agents?api-version=2.3-preview.1
```

Disable/enable build agent (Request method: PATCH)

```
http://[TFS URL]/_apis/distributedtask/pools/[pool id]/agents/[agent id]?api-version=2.3-preview.1
```

Body (`Content-Type: application/json`)

```
{
    "enabled": false,
    "id": [agent id],
    "maxParallelism": 1
}
```

Delete an agent from an agent pool (request method: DELETE):

```
http://[Tfs URL]/_apis/distributedtask/pools/[pool id]/agents/[agent id]?api-version=2.3-preview.1
```

Simple sample to call REST API (PowerShell):

```
Param(
   [string]$vstsAccount = "<VSTS-ACCOUNT-NAME>",
   [string]$projectName = "<PROJECT-NAME>",
   [string]$buildNumber = "<BUILD-NUMBER>",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "<PERSONAL-ACCESS-TOKEN>"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uri = "https://$($vstsAccount).visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/$($projectName)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0&buildNumber=$($buildNumber)"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```

For details: [Calling VSTS APIs with PowerShell](http://blog.devmatter.com/calling-vsts-apis-with-powershell/)

C# code to call REST API:

```
String MyURI = "REST API URL";
WebRequest WReq = WebRequest.Create(MyURI);
WReq.Credentials =
    new NetworkCredential("[user name]", "[password]", "[domain]");

WebResponse response = WReq.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
```

On the other hand, you need to restart the build agent after you install new software to the agent machine in order to recognize them.

Comment: Everything but the disable/enable agent works great. The patch call returns an error. Check my edited question

Comment: @Setorica What're the detail url, body and content-type of your request? You can capture the actual request via developer tool network tracking, then compare with your request through PowerShell. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: How would I use the developer tool to capture that request?

Comment: @Setorica You can refer to this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API to create or remove an agent from the agent pool. And it's not needed to write your own script. When you download the agent, you just need to run a command prompt as Administrator, and then run `ConfigureAgent.cmd` on your build agent machine:

```
C:\Agent\ConfigureAgent.cmd
```

Then respond to the prompts. Check *[Deploy an agent on Windows for TFS 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v1-windows)*