# TFS 2018 Create agent pool programatically

Tags: tfs, automation, tfs-sdk

Is it possible to create an Agent Pool in TFS 2018 programatically, preferably via PowerShell? I cannot find anything like that in REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it's not well-documented, but this just worked for me against VSTS:

```
$token = 'myPAT'
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes((":{0}" -f $token)))

$uri = 'https://<url>/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=4.1-preview.1'
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} `
-Body (ConvertTo-Json @{name = 'foo'; autoProvision = $true})
```

I just looked at the REST API used in the web portal to create an agent pool and copied it; if the API version isn't the same in TFS 2018 as it is in VSTS, you can do the same thing to find the correct version to use.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API of TFS has **an undocumented portion** that deals with app pools: `_apis/distributedtask/pools`. For example:

*Get agent pools (Request method: Get):*

```
http://[TFS URL]/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=x.x-preview.1`
```

api-version should match your TFS version

You could  open up Chrome/IE Network inspector and found that the API calls for create agent pool action. How to do this please refer:

- [Analyzing your webpage's network traffic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255004(v=vs.85))
- [Using Windows Internet Explorer Developer Tools Network Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Finally, you just need to call REST API through PowerShell, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41277388/5391065).

Comment: Thank you. I accepted @Daniel Mann answer because it was basically the same. Do you please have any idea why is this part undocumented? Is it likely to change in future versions of TFS?

Comment: @ppa Sorry, have no idea about this. *Is it likely to change in future versions of TFS?*   Haven't heard  it.  However, even it's not well-documented, but you could still use that. And you could also use Network inspector to verify the API.