# TFS 2018 set security for environment in release definition via script

Tags: rest, tfs, release

I need to create a script that sets security to a given environment in a given release definition (as input I have TFS url, project ID, release ID and environment ID).

With the script, I need to set all the environment specific permissions:

- Administer release permissions
- Delete release environment
- Edit release environment
- Manage deployments
- Manage release approvers

I did not find any method for this in the API. 
I also tried to sniff the network traffic as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554334/tfs-2018-create-agent-pool-programatically). But for this task it looks too difficult. The request body is full of some identifiers (I do not know where how to get them).

The question is: how can I set environment specific permissions via script? 
 (preferably with PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way at the moment is to use tfssecurity.exe!
Here is a good guide and also a download of an Excel that helps you to create your tfssecurity statements. You can find tfssecurity.exe in your TFS-Folder.
Link to guide: https://roadtoalm.com/2014/07/28/add-permissions-with-tfssecuritythe-ultimate-reference/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I briefly looked at it but did not find any "release stuff". Are you sure I can set the permissions for an environment in a release definition via tfssecurity.exe?

Comment: Imho the release stuff is only build stuff in another view - you can use normal build tasks in a release...also the agent is the same, so why do you think it should not work.
Think you only have to write a little powershell which invokes the exe.