# Trying to create a Devops Agent pool using REST api

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to create an agent pool (Azure devops Server) using powershell and invoke-restmethod. To do this I'm using the reference below to try a build up a correct json request body.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
All basics in place (credentials etc - I have successfully run other tasks using other uris)
Many attempts at finding the correct body, all pretty much with the same result, latest example below;

```
$requestBodyAgentPool = '{
    "Id": "3"
    "name": "Testpool",
    "isHosted": $false,
    "autoSize": $false,
    "poolType": "automation",
    "isLegacy": $false
}'
```

Using the following (verified the uri and credentials by running a GET)

```
$uriPool = "http://localhost/DefaultCollection/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=5.1"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriPool -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $requestBodyAgentPool -Credential $cred
```

Fails with below which to me means the parameter id is null.

Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: pool.Name","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, 
mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

I have a feeling this is just my inexperience with coding terms and reading the reference documentation but it is not clear to me if the format is wrong or I'm missing/wrong format a mandatory parameter (id or name?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you could use some UI tool such as Postman to verify if you are able to run same Rest API. This will help you narrow down the issue.

```
{
"name": "{poolname}",
"autoProvision": $true
}
```

The request body should be a **json** format.  Try to explicitly add **ConvertTo-Json** for your post body.

More details take a look at Daniel's reply in this link: [TFS 2018 Create agent pool programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554334/tfs-2018-create-agent-pool-programatically?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: definitely overthinking this one. 

$jsonBodyAgentPool = @{name = 'foo'; autoProvision = $true}

$body = ($jsonBodyAgentPool | ConvertTo-Json)

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriPool -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $body -Credential $cred